Setting Up Laravel Breeze Login and Sign up interface
I installed The Laravel Breeze Package for Authentication . all went well , but when I click on Log in , the page has no css with a error line of code up. I tried reinstalling Breeze and do it all again , changing the Environment from VS Code to Intelij
here is the ligne of code I get on top of the HTML page
@vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
The Sign up and login is woking 100%
reinstalling Breeze and do it all again

So the problem is that your css is not loaded? Or is the problem in the error line? What does the error say?

I know this will be a weird question but, do you have vite running?

npm run build or npm run dev to compile the assets.
